# Making the type signature independent of a specific monad transformer stack (Scala)

Tags: scala, haskell, monads

I'm learning Scala by translating a Haskell function to Scala. I have a monad transformer stack containing the StateMonad

```
type TI a = ...
```

One function using this monad transformer stack is:

```
fresh :: TI Int
fresh = do n <- get
           put (n + 1)
           return n
```

Since this function only depends on the State monad I may also change the type to:

```
fresh :: (MonadState Int m) => m Int
```

How does this translate to Scala? In Scala, I use a monad transformer stack composing the state and the identity monad:

```
type TI[A] = StateT[Id, scala.Int, A]
```

The fresh function in Scala looks like this:

```
def fresh:TI[Ty] = for {
  counter <- get[scala.Int]
  _ <- put[scala.Int] (counter + 1)
} yield {
  TyVar(counter)
}
```

How do I rewrite the type signature in Scala in such a way that in only depends on the State monad and not on the whole monad transformer stack?

Answer (score 4):

Scalaz also provides a `MonadState` type class, although the limitations of Scala's type inference means it's much less elegant. You could write the following, for example:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def fresh[F[_, _]](implicit m: MonadState[F, Int]): F[Int, Int] = for {
  counter <- m.get
  _       <- m.put(counter + 1)
} yield counter
```

And then for example the following:

```
scala> fresh[State]
res6: scalaz.State[Int,Int] = scalaz.IndexedStateT$$anon$10@6517b62

scala> type OptionState[s, a] = StateT[Option, s, a]
defined type alias OptionState

scala> fresh[OptionState]
res7: OptionState[Int,Int] = scalaz.IndexedStateT$$anon$10@43740ba6
```

Note that the first type parameter for `MonadState` needs to have holes for both the state and the value, so you'll need to adjust your `TI` if you want to use this approach—`fresh[TI]` won't work as is.