# Monad Transformer stacks in Scala

Tags: scala, stack, state, monads, either

I'm learning about monad transformers in Scala but I ran into a problem which I find impossible to solve so far. In my monad transformer stack I compose the Either and the State monad. However, I fail to call functions belonging to one of the two monads:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

object Minimal {
  type Inner[A] = EitherT[Id, String, A]
  type Outer[F[+_], A] = StateT[F,Int,A]
  type Stack[A] = Outer[Inner, A]

  def foo:Stack[Int] = for {
    n <- get[Int]
  } yield {
    2 * n
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val x = foo.eval(8)
    println(x)
  }
}
```

Fails with the following error message:

```
[error] Minimal.scala:10: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scalaz.IndexedStateT[scalaz.Id.Id,Int,Int,Int]
[error]  required: Minimal.Stack[Int]
[error]     (which expands to)  scalaz.IndexedStateT[Minimal.Inner,Int,Int,Int]
[error]     n <- get[Int]
```

If I change the monad transformer stack to:

```
type Stack[A] = State[Int,A]
```

The program compiles and runs without a problem. Does anybody knows what I do wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method call `get[Int]` returns an `IndexedStateT[Id, Int, Int, Int]`. Your `Stack[Int]` expands to `IndexedStateT[Inner, Int, Int, Int]` where `Inner` is an `EitherT[Id, String, A]`. This is a bit hard to reason about, so I will simplify your example a bit.

Instead of the `Inner` type alias we create a `StateT` with an `Option`.

```
type Stack[A] = StateT[Option, Int, A]
```

The assignment of `get[Int]` will still fail.

```
val x:Stack[Int] = get[Int]
//type mismatch; 
//  found : scalaz.State[Int,Int]
//    (which expands to) scalaz.IndexedStateT[scalaz.Id.Id,Int,Int,Int]
//  required: Minimal.Stack[Int] 
//    (which expands to) scalaz.IndexedStateT[Option,Int,Int,Int]
```

In order to fix this problem we need to `lift` the transformer to an `Option`:

```
val x:Stack[Int] = get[Int].lift[Option]
```

If you translate that to your example code, you would need to `lift` the `State` to an `Inner` like this. Note that you need to change your definition of `Inner` to be covariant as well:

```
type Inner[+A] = EitherT[Id, String, A]
type Stack[A] = StateT[Inner, Int, A]

val x:Stack[Int] = get[Int].lift[Inner]
```

To be able to write this without lifting manually you could introduce an implicit conversion. The full example:

```
type Inner[+A] = EitherT[Id, String, A]
type Outer[F[+_], A] = StateT[F, Int, A]
type Stack[A] = Outer[Inner, A]

implicit def liftToStack[A](x:Outer[Id, A]):Stack[A] = x.lift[Inner]

def foo: Stack[Int] = for {
  n <- get[Int]
} yield {
  2 * n
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I started writing this as a comment on [EECOLOR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596816/eecolor)'s answer (which I've just upvoted, and which I recommend—apart from the implicit conversion at the end), but it got a little unwieldy, so here's a new answer.

EECOLOR's diagnosis is exactly right, but `MonadState` (which I used in [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22637493/334519) this morning) lets you avoid the explicit lifting. For example, you could write the following:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

type Inner[+A] = EitherT[Id, String, A]
type Stack[S, +A] = StateT[Inner, S, A]

def foo: Stack[Int, Int] = for {
  n <- MonadState[Stack, Int].get
} yield 2 * n
```

Note that (as in my earlier question) I've changed `Stack` to be parametrized on the state type. You could easily change this to something like this:

```
type MyState[S, +A] = StateT[Inner, S, A]
type Stack[+A] = MyState[Int, A]
```

If you wanted to capture the state type in the stack.

Comment: I didn't know about MonadState. That's awesome! Thanks for sharing.